# How to make collection view header and cells the same size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have created a collection view with multiple sections. I want the header view and the collection view cells to be the same size.

I've tried several things:

- Setting insets on the collection view, which seems to have no effect on the cells or the headers.
- Changed referenceSizeForHeaderInSection which also seems to have no effect.
- Changed the size of the view in the Xib associate with the reusable view.
- Constrained the UILabel within the Xib to 0 from the top, left, right, and bottom and set the width the 300, but this seems to be overridden (see below, the blacked out areas in the picture are the app name).

[Screenshot of constraints being broke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Xwk.png)

Below are some of my methods:

viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30)

    collectionViewHeightAnchor.constant = view.frame.height / 2

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CollectionReusableView", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(nib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "groceryHeader")
}
```

Collection view delegate/datasource and header setup

```
// MARK: - Header

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return foodItems.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 120, height: 45)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let (key, _) = foodItems[indexPath.section]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "groceryHeader", for: indexPath) as! CollectionReusableView
    cell.lbl.text = key

    return cell
}



// MARK: - Cell

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foodItems[section].1.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 120, height: 45)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "foodCell", for: indexPath)
    if let cell = cell as? FoodItemCell {
        let (_, val) = foodItems[indexPath.section]
        cell.titleLbl.text = val[indexPath.row].text
        cell.quantityLbl.text = val[indexPath.row].quantity
        cell.postId = val[indexPath.row].id

        if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.getCheckedIds() {
            cell.checkBoxImg.setImage(arr.contains(val[indexPath.row].id) ? UIImage(named: "checked") : UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the width of your headers to be a certain size. The default for UICollectionViewFlowLayout is to fill the width of the collection view.

You have a few options here:

1) Create a custom layout that sizes the supplementary views (headers) at the desired size. This would probably be considered the "correct" option but is probably more complicated than you need.

2) Just add a "container" view to your header view, set the width to your desired size (120) and center X to the parent. If the root collection view element (UICollectionReusabableView) is transparent it won't show leaving your subview (the "container") as the only visible view.

3) Unless you are using UICollectionViewController you could just set the width of the collection view to your desired size (120). If you **are** using UICollectionViewController, you *could* replace it with a UIViewController, add a UICollectionView and set the dataSource and delegate to the UIViewController. This way the headers, under the default flow layout, would fill the cv, which would only be as wide as you need.